# Locale wrongly configured

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, locale

I have just launched an EC2 machine, in the frankfurt region. The locale is corrupted:

```
ubuntu@myhost:~$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

How can I correct the issue?

Comment: Ask amazon to reset the machine? Or reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @tripleee Similar, yes. I documented my solution as answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/locale.gen`:

```
sudo vi /etc/locale.gen
```

And make sure that:

```
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

is uncommented. Then just do:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

And verify:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.gen | grep -v '^#'
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```